# Can the asp.net mvc server see controls created dynamically when the parent of them performs a submit?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I want to create with Javascript some controls inside a form and then I want to submit it to the server.

Can the server read these controls created dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. MVC is essentially stateless. Remember, this isn't ASP.NET Webforms - "controls" don't exist in same way they did. When you do a POST, you are simply sending form field name/value pairs. If the name of a field corresponds to a property in your model, or a parameter to your action, it will bind.

Comment: thanks bhamlin  therefore 
it is not possible to post back  form with  input control of type= file  created with javascript?

Comment: check out http://interactiveasp.net/blogs/spgilmore/archive/2009/06/03/how-to-support-file-uploads-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx. You probably need to put the  `enctype` attribute on your form element.

Comment: it can sees file uploaders created at design time but not with javascript